# IPython - single line spacing possible?

Tags: command-prompt, ipython

By default, the IPython shell shows a blank line between inputs:

```
In [1]: 1 + 1
Out[1]: 2

In [2]: import math

In [3]: math.sqrt(2)
Out[3]: 1.4142135623730951

In [4]:
```

Is there any way to configure the IPython shell so that it does not produce a blank line between each command history? This would significantly increase the amount of history I would be able to see on my screen.

Comment: The magic command `hist` (short for `history`) prints input history without blank lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on Windows, Alok's excerp didn't differ from the default content of these three lines in my `%USERPROFILE%/_ipython/ipythonrc.ini`

I rather had to change the line:

```
separate_in \n
```

to:

```
separate_in 0
```

Comment: That works.  Or `nosep 1`, which is a shortcut for `separate_in 0`, `separate_out 0` and `separate_out2 0` (the last two are 0 by default anyway).

Answer (score 8):

For Mac users, the profile config to permanently edit this can be found in: 
  /Users/(your username)/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py

For linux users, it's probably a nearly identical path, but with /home/ instead of /Users/. Using '~' in the command line will work in either case, (e.g. ~/.ipython/...).

Un-comment line 164 and remove the newline, so it says:

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.separate_in = ''
```

While this is an old question, it's still relevant for other users (such as myself) who find it via Google, so I wanted to add this answer for Mac & Linux users.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `--nosep` option. e.g.

`C:\Python32\Scripts\ipython3.exe --nosep`