# IPython 5.0: Remove spaces between input lines

Tags: python, ipython, prompt

(This question is essentially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351857/ipython-single-line-spacing-possible), but for IPython version 5.0)

I'd like to have a classic prompt with IPython 5.0.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275585/adding-color-to-new-style-ipython-v5-prompt) question helps customize my prompt. In fact, I discovered that IPython has a class definition for the [`ClassicPrompts`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/generated/IPython.terminal.prompts.html#IPython.terminal.prompts.ClassicPrompts) already.

All I need to do is to put the following in a file called `00-classic-prompts.py` or some such in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`:

```
from IPython.terminal.prompts import ClassicPrompts

ip = get_ipython()
ip.prompts = ClassicPrompts(ip)
```

But different prompt lines still render as:

```
>>> print('Hello world!')
Hello world!

>>>
```

With an extra new-line before every input prompt. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please append this line on the bottom of your existing startup script:

```
ip.separate_in = ''
```

This is a [documented feature](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/options/terminal.html) but currently has no description, making it hard-to-find.

Comment: @wim For future reference, is this documented somewhere? I tried looking on their [new docs website](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/details.html#custom-prompts), but found nothing. Thanks!