# Add blank lines back to iPython history in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython

I am using PyCharm as my IDE, but having trouble configuring the history display in the iPython Console. When I run iPython straight from my terminal, I get the desired result below where input lines in the history are separated by a blank line:

[image: Desired result]

However, inside PyCharm the history of commands gets "squashed" together so that there are no blank lines (only the one between the most recent history and the current input line):

[image]

I find this difficult to read and would prefer to configure PyCharm so it reproduces the behavior in the first image. Essentially, I need to do the opposite of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351857/ipython-single-line-spacing-possible). I've tried creating a `ipythonrc` file under `~/.ipython/profile_default`, adding a line with `separate_in \n`, and re-launching PyCharm's iPython console, but this did not solve my problem.

Details:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- iPython 7.2.0
- PyCharm 2018.3 Community Edition
- Python 3.7.1